# Training wordvec in Tensorflow, importing to Gensim

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, gensim

I am training a word2vec model from the tensorflow tutorial.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py

After training I get the embedding matrix. I would like to save this and import it as a trained model in gensim.

To load a model in gensim, the command is:

```
model = Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format(fn, binary=True)
```

But how do I generate the `fn` file from Tensorflow?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to is save the file in the non-binary Word2Vec format, which essentially looks like this:

```
num_words vector_size  # this is the header
label0 x00 x01 ... x0N
label1 x10 x11 ... x1N
...
```

Example:

```
2 3
word0 -0.000737 -0.002106 0.001851
word1 -0.000878 -0.002106 0.002834
```

Save the file and then load with kwarg `binary=False`:

```
model = Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format(filename, binary=False)

print(model['word0'])
```

### Update

New way to load model is:

```
from gensim.models.keyedvectors import KeyedVectors

model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(model_path, binary=False)
```

Comment: so I would need to generate a txt file which follows your example format above. The save it as txt (or w2v), and then open it in gensim as per your last line?

Comment: Exactly that's all you have to do. Once loaded you can save in the gensim format.