# Importing word vectors from tensorflow into gensim

Tags: python, tensorflow, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

I want to import word vecters created from tensorflow and utilize it at gensim.

there is a method `gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format`

so I tried this method by following exactly the same way in [Training wordvec in Tensorflow, importing to Gensim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186543/training-wordvec-in-tensorflow-importing-to-gensim)

Example:

> 2 3
>
> word0 -0.000737 -0.002106 0.001851
>
> word1 -0.000878 -0.002106 0.002834

Save the file and then load with kwarg binary=False:

```
model = Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format(filename, binary=False)
```

but error like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    model=gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('test.w2v')
  File "C:\Users\cbj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py", line 243, in load_word2vec_format
    raise EOFError("unexpected end of input; is count incorrect or file otherwise damaged?")
EOFError: unexpected end of input; is count incorrect or file otherwise damaged?
```

raised

how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is raised when the number of vector data doesn't match the number you provided at the first line.

If the first line wrote `2 3`, you should have exactly `2` lines below. Make sure that there's no empty line at the end of your file and of course some where in your file.